# Passenger Full Queue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger, passenger-nginx

Whenever we get large traffic spikes on our Rails 4 app, it seems passenger can't handle the load and starts showing the dreaded `This website is under heavy load (queue full)` error page.

I'm trying to optimize things as much as i can on the app side, but looking at the status of passenger when this occurs, seems to me a lot of the processes are just stuck:

```
sudo passenger-status
Version : 5.3.5
Date    : 2021-03-18 21:59:52 +0000
Instance: xGyoOAEC (nginx/1.18.0 Phusion_Passenger/5.3.5)

----------- General information -----------
Max pool size : 160
App groups    : 2
Processes     : 160
Requests in top-level queue : 0

----------- Application groups -----------
/var/www/app1 (production):
  App root: /var/www/app1
  Requests in queue: 0
  * PID: 18014   Sessions: 1       Processed: 113     Uptime: 9m 21s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 170M    Last used: 1s ago
  * PID: 18076   Sessions: 0       Processed: 12      Uptime: 9m 19s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 131M    Last used: 1m 44s ago

/var/www/app2 (production):
  App root: /var/www/app2
  Requests in queue: 250
  * PID: 17786   Sessions: 1       Processed: 13      Uptime: 9m 24s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 85M     Last used: 1m 24s ago
  * PID: 17833   Sessions: 1       Processed: 23      Uptime: 9m 22s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 119M    Last used: 1m 22s ago
  * PID: 17978   Sessions: 1       Processed: 16      Uptime: 9m 21s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 118M    Last used: 1m 20s ago
  * PID: 18122   Sessions: 1       Processed: 16      Uptime: 9m 19s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 102M    Last used: 1m 18s ago
  * PID: 18183   Sessions: 1       Processed: 11      Uptime: 9m 17s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 95M     Last used: 1m 16s ago
  * PID: 18233   Sessions: 1       Processed: 5       Uptime: 9m 15s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 117M    Last used: 1m 14s ago
  * PID: 18289   Sessions: 1       Processed: 14      Uptime: 9m 13s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 124M    Last used: 3m 13s ago
  * PID: 18351   Sessions: 1       Processed: 18      Uptime: 9m 11s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 96M     Last used: 1m 11s ago
  * PID: 18411   Sessions: 1       Processed: 24      Uptime: 9m 10s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 97M     Last used: 1m 9s ago
  * PID: 18463   Sessions: 1       Processed: 14      Uptime: 9m 8s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 98M     Last used: 1m 7s ago
  * PID: 18516   Sessions: 1       Processed: 29      Uptime: 9m 6s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 98M     Last used: 1m 5s ago
  * PID: 18575   Sessions: 1       Processed: 15      Uptime: 9m 4s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 95M     Last used: 1m 4s ago
  * PID: 18623   Sessions: 1       Processed: 22      Uptime: 9m 2s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 100M    Last used: 1m 2s ago
  * PID: 18673   Sessions: 1       Processed: 32      Uptime: 9m 1s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 99M     Last used: 1m 0s ago
  * PID: 18729   Sessions: 1       Processed: 15      Uptime: 8m 59s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 86M     Last used: 58s ago
  * PID: 18788   Sessions: 1       Processed: 19      Uptime: 8m 57s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 96M     Last used: 56s ago
  * PID: 18839   Sessions: 1       Processed: 29      Uptime: 8m 55s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 98M     Last used: 54s ago
  * PID: 18895   Sessions: 1       Processed: 18      Uptime: 8m 53s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 85M     Last used: 53s ago
  * PID: 18944   Sessions: 1       Processed: 19      Uptime: 8m 51s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 103M    Last used: 51s ago
  * PID: 18998   Sessions: 1       Processed: 10      Uptime: 8m 50s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 97M     Last used: 2m 49s ago
  * PID: 19061   Sessions: 1       Processed: 32      Uptime: 8m 48s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 98M     Last used: 47s ago
  * PID: 19125   Sessions: 1       Processed: 17      Uptime: 8m 46s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 99M     Last used: 45s ago
  * PID: 19183   Sessions: 1       Processed: 10      Uptime: 8m 44s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 118M    Last used: 43s ago
  * PID: 19232   Sessions: 1       Processed: 8       Uptime: 8m 42s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 98M     Last used: 42s ago
  * PID: 19286   Sessions: 1       Processed: 36      Uptime: 8m 41s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 118M    Last used: 40s ago
  * PID: 19342   Sessions: 1       Processed: 16      Uptime: 8m 39s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 118M    Last used: 38s ago
  * PID: 19395   Sessions: 1       Processed: 12      Uptime: 8m 37s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 98M     Last used: 36s ago
  * PID: 19445   Sessions: 1       Processed: 11      Uptime: 8m 35s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 95M     Last used: 2m 35s ago
  * PID: 19504   Sessions: 1       Processed: 12      Uptime: 8m 33s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 103M    Last used: 33s ago
  * PID: 19557   Sessions: 1       Processed: 37      Uptime: 8m 31s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 102M    Last used: 31s ago
  * PID: 19608   Sessions: 1       Processed: 11      Uptime: 8m 30s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 116M    Last used: 29s ago
  * PID: 19664   Sessions: 1       Processed: 14      Uptime: 8m 28s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 119M    Last used: 27s ago
  * PID: 19712   Sessions: 1       Processed: 19      Uptime: 8m 26s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 97M     Last used: 25s ago
  * PID: 19774   Sessions: 1       Processed: 22      Uptime: 8m 24s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 100M    Last used: 23s ago
  * PID: 19824   Sessions: 1       Processed: 19      Uptime: 8m 22s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 115M    Last used: 21s ago
  * PID: 19954   Sessions: 1       Processed: 12      Uptime: 8m 20s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 95M     Last used: 20s ago
  * PID: 20021   Sessions: 1       Processed: 4       Uptime: 8m 19s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 117M    Last used: 18s ago
  * PID: 20073   Sessions: 1       Processed: 16      Uptime: 8m 17s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 96M     Last used: 16s ago
  * PID: 20124   Sessions: 1       Processed: 11      Uptime: 8m 15s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 95M     Last used: 14s ago
  * PID: 20182   Sessions: 1       Processed: 19      Uptime: 8m 13s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 106M    Last used: 13s ago
  * PID: 20236   Sessions: 1       Processed: 8       Uptime: 8m 11s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 100M    Last used: 11s ago
  * PID: 20287   Sessions: 1       Processed: 16      Uptime: 8m 10s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 98M     Last used: 9s ago
  * PID: 20344   Sessions: 1       Processed: 7       Uptime: 8m 8s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 100M    Last used: 7s ago
  * PID: 20397   Sessions: 1       Processed: 17      Uptime: 8m 6s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 96M     Last used: 5s ago
  * PID: 20456   Sessions: 1       Processed: 11      Uptime: 8m 4s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 118M    Last used: 3s ago
  * PID: 20510   Sessions: 1       Processed: 16      Uptime: 8m 2s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 117M    Last used: 2s ago
  * PID: 20565   Sessions: 1       Processed: 6       Uptime: 8m 1s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 97M     Last used: 2m 0s ago
  * PID: 20622   Sessions: 1       Processed: 8       Uptime: 7m 59s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 94M     Last used: 1m 58s ago
  * PID: 20674   Sessions: 1       Processed: 9       Uptime: 7m 57s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 120M    Last used: 1m 56s ago
  * PID: 20726   Sessions: 1       Processed: 12      Uptime: 7m 55s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 118M    Last used: 1m 54s ago
  * PID: 20784   Sessions: 1       Processed: 25      Uptime: 7m 53s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 97M     Last used: 1m 53s ago
  * PID: 20833   Sessions: 1       Processed: 6       Uptime: 7m 51s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 117M    Last used: 1m 51s ago
  * PID: 20889   Sessions: 1       Processed: 3       Uptime: 7m 50s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 84M     Last used: 5m 49s ago
  * PID: 20951   Sessions: 1       Processed: 19      Uptime: 7m 48s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 99M     Last used: 1m 47s ago
  * PID: 21016   Sessions: 1       Processed: 25      Uptime: 7m 46s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 100M    Last used: 1m 46s ago
  * PID: 21068   Sessions: 1       Processed: 5       Uptime: 7m 44s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 94M     Last used: 1m 44s ago
  * PID: 21128   Sessions: 1       Processed: 6       Uptime: 7m 42s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 85M     Last used: 1m 42s ago
  * PID: 21180   Sessions: 1       Processed: 23      Uptime: 7m 41s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 99M     Last used: 1m 40s ago
  * PID: 21238   Sessions: 1       Processed: 10      Uptime: 7m 39s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 97M     Last used: 1m 38s ago
  * PID: 21290   Sessions: 1       Processed: 14      Uptime: 7m 37s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 85M     Last used: 1m 37s ago
  * PID: 21341   Sessions: 1       Processed: 9       Uptime: 7m 35s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 97M     Last used: 1m 35s ago
  * PID: 21399   Sessions: 1       Processed: 13      Uptime: 7m 33s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 98M     Last used: 1m 33s ago
  * PID: 21448   Sessions: 1       Processed: 11      Uptime: 7m 32s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 91M     Last used: 5m 31s ago
  * PID: 21500   Sessions: 1       Processed: 12      Uptime: 7m 30s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 95M     Last used: 1m 29s ago
  * PID: 21557   Sessions: 1       Processed: 17      Uptime: 7m 28s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 98M     Last used: 1m 27s ago
  * PID: 21606   Sessions: 1       Processed: 8       Uptime: 7m 26s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 85M     Last used: 1m 26s ago
  * PID: 21657   Sessions: 1       Processed: 22      Uptime: 7m 24s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 86M     Last used: 1m 24s ago
  * PID: 21715   Sessions: 1       Processed: 13      Uptime: 7m 22s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 97M     Last used: 1m 22s ago
  * PID: 21844   Sessions: 1       Processed: 8       Uptime: 7m 21s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 90M     Last used: 5m 20s ago
  * PID: 21912   Sessions: 1       Processed: 21      Uptime: 7m 19s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 96M     Last used: 1m 18s ago
  * PID: 21969   Sessions: 1       Processed: 7       Uptime: 7m 17s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 94M     Last used: 1m 16s ago
  * PID: 22052   Sessions: 1       Processed: 28      Uptime: 7m 15s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 121M    Last used: 1m 14s ago
  * PID: 22119   Sessions: 1       Processed: 16      Uptime: 7m 13s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 95M     Last used: 1m 13s ago
  * PID: 22190   Sessions: 1       Processed: 21      Uptime: 7m 11s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 99M     Last used: 1m 11s ago
  * PID: 22262   Sessions: 1       Processed: 8       Uptime: 7m 10s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 85M     Last used: 1m 9s ago
  * PID: 22321   Sessions: 1       Processed: 14      Uptime: 7m 8s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 85M     Last used: 1m 8s ago
  * PID: 22373   Sessions: 1       Processed: 8       Uptime: 7m 6s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 117M    Last used: 1m 5s ago
  * PID: 22429   Sessions: 1       Processed: 14      Uptime: 7m 4s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 95M     Last used: 1m 4s ago
  * PID: 22488   Sessions: 1       Processed: 19      Uptime: 7m 2s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 85M     Last used: 1m 2s ago
  * PID: 22542   Sessions: 1       Processed: 8       Uptime: 7m 0s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 94M     Last used: 1m 0s ago
  * PID: 22601   Sessions: 1       Processed: 16      Uptime: 6m 59s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 96M     Last used: 58s ago
  * PID: 22655   Sessions: 1       Processed: 6       Uptime: 6m 57s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 96M     Last used: 56s ago
  * PID: 22714   Sessions: 1       Processed: 24      Uptime: 6m 55s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 96M     Last used: 55s ago
  * PID: 22772   Sessions: 1       Processed: 8       Uptime: 6m 53s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 97M     Last used: 53s ago
  * PID: 22822   Sessions: 1       Processed: 21      Uptime: 6m 51s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 96M     Last used: 51s ago
  * PID: 22878   Sessions: 1       Processed: 13      Uptime: 6m 50s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 115M    Last used: 49s ago
  * PID: 22938   Sessions: 1       Processed: 14      Uptime: 6m 48s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 86M     Last used: 47s ago
  * PID: 23008   Sessions: 1       Processed: 22      Uptime: 6m 46s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 96M     Last used: 45s ago
  * PID: 23060   Sessions: 1       Processed: 16      Uptime: 6m 44s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 117M    Last used: 43s ago
  * PID: 23118   Sessions: 1       Processed: 6       Uptime: 6m 42s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 94M     Last used: 42s ago
  * PID: 23171   Sessions: 1       Processed: 9       Uptime: 6m 40s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 117M    Last used: 40s ago
  * PID: 23230   Sessions: 1       Processed: 11      Uptime: 6m 39s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 118M    Last used: 38s ago
  * PID: 23284   Sessions: 1       Processed: 3       Uptime: 6m 37s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 84M     Last used: 36s ago
  * PID: 23341   Sessions: 1       Processed: 8       Uptime: 6m 35s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 94M     Last used: 34s ago
  * PID: 23399   Sessions: 1       Processed: 6       Uptime: 6m 33s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 94M     Last used: 33s ago
  * PID: 23452   Sessions: 1       Processed: 4       Uptime: 6m 31s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 94M     Last used: 2m 31s ago
  * PID: 23503   Sessions: 1       Processed: 12      Uptime: 6m 29s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 95M     Last used: 29s ago
  * PID: 23562   Sessions: 1       Processed: 23      Uptime: 6m 28s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 96M     Last used: 27s ago
  * PID: 23613   Sessions: 1       Processed: 14      Uptime: 6m 26s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 85M     Last used: 25s ago
  * PID: 23667   Sessions: 1       Processed: 17      Uptime: 6m 24s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 117M    Last used: 23s ago
  * PID: 23727   Sessions: 1       Processed: 20      Uptime: 6m 22s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 96M     Last used: 22s ago
  * PID: 23857   Sessions: 1       Processed: 20      Uptime: 6m 20s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 96M     Last used: 20s ago
  * PID: 23914   Sessions: 1       Processed: 14      Uptime: 6m 19s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 85M     Last used: 18s ago
  * PID: 23977   Sessions: 1       Processed: 20      Uptime: 6m 17s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 86M     Last used: 16s ago
  * PID: 24031   Sessions: 1       Processed: 8       Uptime: 6m 15s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 117M    Last used: 14s ago
  * PID: 24091   Sessions: 1       Processed: 13      Uptime: 6m 13s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 117M    Last used: 13s ago
  * PID: 24143   Sessions: 1       Processed: 12      Uptime: 6m 11s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 95M     Last used: 11s ago
  * PID: 24212   Sessions: 1       Processed: 14      Uptime: 6m 10s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 98M     Last used: 9s ago
  * PID: 24271   Sessions: 1       Processed: 25      Uptime: 6m 8s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 96M     Last used: 7s ago
  * PID: 24328   Sessions: 1       Processed: 19      Uptime: 6m 6s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 95M     Last used: 5s ago
  * PID: 24382   Sessions: 1       Processed: 9       Uptime: 6m 4s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 95M     Last used: 3s ago
  * PID: 24440   Sessions: 1       Processed: 10      Uptime: 6m 2s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 94M     Last used: 2s ago
  * PID: 24495   Sessions: 1       Processed: 7       Uptime: 6m 0s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 94M     Last used: 2m 0s ago
  * PID: 24547   Sessions: 1       Processed: 8       Uptime: 5m 59s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 85M     Last used: 5m 58s ago
  * PID: 24611   Sessions: 1       Processed: 13      Uptime: 5m 57s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 95M     Last used: 1m 56s ago
  * PID: 24665   Sessions: 1       Processed: 4       Uptime: 5m 55s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 117M    Last used: 1m 54s ago
  * PID: 24729   Sessions: 1       Processed: 6       Uptime: 5m 53s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 93M     Last used: 1m 53s ago
  * PID: 24781   Sessions: 1       Processed: 3       Uptime: 5m 51s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 84M     Last used: 1m 51s ago
  * PID: 24839   Sessions: 1       Processed: 25      Uptime: 5m 49s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 86M     Last used: 1m 49s ago
  * PID: 24906   Sessions: 1       Processed: 1       Uptime: 5m 48s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 84M     Last used: 5m 47s ago
  * PID: 24973   Sessions: 1       Processed: 9       Uptime: 5m 46s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 94M     Last used: 1m 45s ago
  * PID: 25031   Sessions: 1       Processed: 8       Uptime: 5m 44s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 85M     Last used: 1m 44s ago
  * PID: 25090   Sessions: 1       Processed: 3       Uptime: 5m 42s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 95M     Last used: 1m 42s ago
  * PID: 25144   Sessions: 1       Processed: 8       Uptime: 5m 40s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 117M    Last used: 1m 40s ago
  * PID: 25196   Sessions: 1       Processed: 22      Uptime: 5m 38s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 96M     Last used: 1m 38s ago
  * PID: 25258   Sessions: 1       Processed: 6       Uptime: 5m 37s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 94M     Last used: 1m 36s ago
  * PID: 25313   Sessions: 1       Processed: 11      Uptime: 5m 35s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 94M     Last used: 1m 34s ago
  * PID: 25372   Sessions: 1       Processed: 20      Uptime: 5m 33s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 96M     Last used: 1m 33s ago
  * PID: 25426   Sessions: 1       Processed: 13      Uptime: 5m 31s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 95M     Last used: 1m 31s ago
  * PID: 25478   Sessions: 1       Processed: 3       Uptime: 5m 29s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 93M     Last used: 1m 29s ago
  * PID: 25545   Sessions: 1       Processed: 11      Uptime: 5m 28s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 94M     Last used: 1m 27s ago
  * PID: 25607   Sessions: 1       Processed: 3       Uptime: 5m 26s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 93M     Last used: 1m 25s ago
  * PID: 25658   Sessions: 1       Processed: 10      Uptime: 5m 24s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 97M     Last used: 1m 23s ago
  * PID: 25720   Sessions: 1       Processed: 14      Uptime: 5m 22s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 118M    Last used: 1m 22s ago
  * PID: 25850   Sessions: 1       Processed: 7       Uptime: 5m 20s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 123M    Last used: 1m 20s ago
  * PID: 25909   Sessions: 1       Processed: 5       Uptime: 5m 18s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 84M     Last used: 1m 18s ago
  * PID: 25973   Sessions: 1       Processed: 17      Uptime: 5m 17s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 98M     Last used: 1m 16s ago
  * PID: 26028   Sessions: 1       Processed: 17      Uptime: 5m 15s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 95M     Last used: 1m 14s ago
  * PID: 26095   Sessions: 1       Processed: 2       Uptime: 5m 13s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 95M     Last used: 1m 13s ago
  * PID: 26146   Sessions: 1       Processed: 9       Uptime: 5m 11s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 117M    Last used: 1m 11s ago
  * PID: 26201   Sessions: 1       Processed: 6       Uptime: 5m 9s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 93M     Last used: 1m 9s ago
  * PID: 26264   Sessions: 1       Processed: 18      Uptime: 5m 7s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 95M     Last used: 1m 7s ago
  * PID: 26318   Sessions: 1       Processed: 8       Uptime: 5m 6s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 117M    Last used: 1m 5s ago
  * PID: 26373   Sessions: 1       Processed: 14      Uptime: 5m 4s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 85M     Last used: 1m 3s ago
  * PID: 26439   Sessions: 1       Processed: 13      Uptime: 5m 2s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 97M     Last used: 1m 2s ago
  * PID: 26494   Sessions: 1       Processed: 16      Uptime: 5m 0s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 97M     Last used: 1m 0s ago
  * PID: 26547   Sessions: 1       Processed: 9       Uptime: 4m 58s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 117M    Last used: 58s ago
  * PID: 26610   Sessions: 1       Processed: 3       Uptime: 4m 56s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 93M     Last used: 56s ago
  * PID: 26665   Sessions: 1       Processed: 4       Uptime: 4m 55s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 84M     Last used: 54s ago
  * PID: 26721   Sessions: 1       Processed: 3       Uptime: 4m 53s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 84M     Last used: 52s ago
  * PID: 26777   Sessions: 1       Processed: 8       Uptime: 4m 51s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 94M     Last used: 51s ago
  * PID: 26834   Sessions: 1       Processed: 15      Uptime: 4m 49s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 117M    Last used: 49s ago
  * PID: 26895   Sessions: 1       Processed: 5       Uptime: 4m 47s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 84M     Last used: 47s ago
  * PID: 26963   Sessions: 1       Processed: 8       Uptime: 4m 45s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 97M     Last used: 45s ago
  * PID: 27020   Sessions: 1       Processed: 12      Uptime: 4m 44s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 94M     Last used: 43s ago
  * PID: 27081   Sessions: 1       Processed: 6       Uptime: 4m 42s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 94M     Last used: 41s ago
  * PID: 27136   Sessions: 1       Processed: 6       Uptime: 4m 40s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 84M     Last used: 40s ago
  * PID: 27189   Sessions: 1       Processed: 5       Uptime: 4m 38s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 96M     Last used: 38s ago
```

Any idea what could be causing this and what i could tweak to prevent it?

**EDIT**

`passenger.conf`:

```
passenger_root /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini;
passenger_ruby /usr/bin/passenger_free_ruby;
passenger_max_pool_size 160;
passenger_max_request_queue_size 250;
```

Comment: Please update with all passenger configuration you have. Are those 2 apps different?

Comment: Any APM graphs you have when the site is under load.

Comment: @razvans yes two different apps, i've updated with the passenger configuration, APM graphs available.

Comment: Does this help? https://github.com/phusion/passenger/issues/1621. Does `passenger-status --show=requests` show any useful info?